# How can dynamically add headers to table in this pyqt5 app?

Tags: python, pyqt5

This code I have taken from https://bravo.hatenablog.jp/entry/2016/01/18/093059 .

In this I want to add header "Quantity" at run time if needed.

Before creating table it should ask for how many headers? If user supply 4 then create table with "Quantity" headers also. Otherwise create default headers (Three).

I have tried it but not found any solution.

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Model(QAbstractItemModel):
    headers = "Toppings", "Udon/Soba", "Hot/Cold"
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Model, self).__init__(parent)
        self.items = []

    def index(self, row, column, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return self.createIndex(row, column, None)

    def parent(self, child):
        return QModelIndex()

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.items)

    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.headers)

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            try:
                return self.items[index.row()][index.column()]
            except:
                return
        return

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
            return self.headers[section]

    def addRow(self, topping, menkind, hotcold):
        self.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), len(self.items), 1)
        self.items.append([topping, menkind, hotcold])
        self.endInsertRows()

    def removeRows(self, rowIndexes):
        for row in sorted(rowIndexes, reverse=True):
            self.beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), row, row + 1)
            del self.items[row]
            self.endRemoveRows()

    def flags(self, index):
        return super(Model, self).flags(index) | Qt.ItemIsEditable

    def setData(self, index, value, role=Qt.EditRole):
        if role == Qt.EditRole:
            self.items[index.row()][index.column()] = value
            return True
        return False

class View(QTreeView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(View, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setItemsExpandable(False)
        self.setIndentation(0)
        self.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)

    def drawBranches(self, painter, rect, index):
        return

class InputWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(InputWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        toppings = ("Kitsune", "Tanuki", "Tempura", "Tsukimi", "Meat", "Curry")
        self.toppingInput = QComboBox()
        for topping in toppings:
            self.toppingInput.addItem(topping)
        layout.addWidget(self.toppingInput)

        self.bgrp = QGroupBox()
        udon = QRadioButton('Udon')
        udon.setChecked(True)
        soba = QRadioButton('Soba')
        btnlayout = QHBoxLayout()
        btnlayout.addWidget(udon)
        btnlayout.addWidget(soba)
        self.bgrp.setLayout(btnlayout)
        layout.addWidget(self.bgrp)
        self.udonsoba = udon, soba

        self.bgrp_temp = QGroupBox()
        hot = QRadioButton('Warm')
        hot.setChecked(True)
        cold = QRadioButton('Cold')
        btnlayout_temp = QHBoxLayout()
        btnlayout_temp.addWidget(hot)
        btnlayout_temp.addWidget(cold)
        self.bgrp_temp.setLayout(btnlayout_temp)
        layout.addWidget(self.bgrp_temp)
        self.hotcold = hot, cold

        self.addButton = QPushButton('OK')
        layout.addWidget(self.addButton)

        layout.addStretch()

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def values(self):
        topping = self.toppingInput.currentText()

        udonsoba = '?'
        for btn in self.udonsoba:
            if btn.isChecked():
                udonsoba = btn.text()
                break

        hotcold = '?'
        for btn in self.hotcold:
            if btn.isChecked():
                hotcold = btn.text()
                break

        return topping, udonsoba, hotcold

class Delegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Delegate, self).__init__(parent)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        return QLineEdit(parent)

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        value = index.model().data(index, Qt.DisplayRole)
        editor.setText(value)

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        model.setData(index, editor.text())

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.view = View(self)
        self.model = Model(self)
        self.view.setModel(self.model)
        self.view.setItemDelegate(Delegate())
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)

        self.inputWidget = InputWidget()
        self.inputWidget.addButton.clicked.connect(self.addItem)
        self.addDock = QDockWidget('Input', self)
        self.addDock.setWidget(self.inputWidget)
        self.addDock.setAllowedAreas(Qt.AllDockWidgetAreas)
        self.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, self.addDock)
        self.addDock.hide()

        toolBar = QToolBar()
        self.addToolBar(toolBar)

        delButton = QPushButton('Delete')
        delButton.clicked.connect(self.removeItems)
        toolBar.addWidget(delButton)

        self.addButton = QPushButton('Add')
        self.addButton.clicked.connect(self.addDock.show)
        toolBar.addWidget(self.addButton)

    def addItem(self):
        self.model.addRow(*self.inputWidget.values())

    def selectedRows(self):
        rows = []
        for index in self.view.selectedIndexes():
            if index.column() == 0:
                rows.append(index.row())
        return rows

    def removeItems(self):
        self.model.removeRows(self.selectedRows())

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    w.raise_()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Ideally you'd want to pass in the headers to the class on instantiation, and expose methods to change the headers. Right now your headers are hardcoded, and so there is no way to change them.

Comment: Can you give examples for it ? I am new to PyQt